# redirect aspx page to xaml page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, xaml

I have a startup page as `Menu.aspx` I want to redirect this page to `login.xaml`
so that whenver user type `Menu.aspx` it should open `login.xaml` then this `.aspx` page.

How do I do this? Please help me.

Comment: I don't get it, how do you want to display a xaml page from an aspx page? You'll build your silverlight app which will be a xap file and then load this file on whichever page you want.

Comment: I don't think you can directly do this. But you can create an ASPX and host the silverlight application on the page, you can re-direct to that page.

Answer (score 1):

The browser cannot show directly show a xaml page.  Silverlight is shown through an aspx page with an  tag that contains the silverlight object.  When you create a new project (and select host in a new web project) there is the default.aspx page, in there you will see the  tag I am talking about.

By default the starting page for silverlight is the "MainPage.xaml" if you want to override that, go into your "app.xaml" in the code and modify the object in the Application_Startup event.

Comment: Yes, 1. create a SL project, link it to your website/webapplication project when asked 2. Make a login.aspx in your web project 3. Dump the SL plugin-call in login.aspx 4. Redirect to login.aspx, not login.xaml.